# How to use the Jaeger gRPC stubs for querying metrics?

Tags: microservices, grpc, jaeger

I am trying to get the Jaeger collected metrics from the gRPC API instead of using the JSON file returned by the Web Dashboard.

I generated the gRPC stubs from the [jaeger-idl](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-idl/tree/main) repo but I cannot seem to find a source on how to use the stubs to get the traces. Any help on this?

Comment: You can look at any of 100s of gRPC tutorials to see how to use the stubs. There's nothing special about Jaeger here, just another gRPC endpoint.  What are you missing exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I figured out that Jaeger by default does not open the gRPC endpoint, so the Kubernetes configuration must explicitly open the Jaeger gRPC port - which the documentation shows to be 16686: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.42/deployment/#query-service--ui